# Applying function on columns from multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a function `f(a, b, c)`, that takes 3 different length vectors as params, and returns a 1D array (same length as param `a`). I also have three 2D arrays (`A, B, C`) with different `dtype` and one identical dimension (`N`), while the other dimension is different for all three.

I want to apply `f` in the most efficient way on the 2D arrays along their non-identical length axis, so that `f` gets called with one column (or row, if transposing makes any difference) from each.

A naive approach would be something like zipping the 2D arrays along the identical axis and iterating over the 3-tuples containing one column from each array (ie. calling `f` `N` times), eg. with `N = 3`:

```py
A = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
B = np.arange(12).reshape(4, 3)
C = np.arange(15).reshape(5, 3)

result = np.array([f(a, b, c) for a, b, c in zip(A.T, B.T, C.T)])
```

Real `N` in my case is ~30K, while the other dimension of the arrays varies between 5 and ~1000.

Is there a (significantly) more performant way with arrays of this size, either using pure Python or `numpy`?

Comment: You have [`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html), but that is not much better than looping. As usual, whether this can be done efficiently depends on the the particular function `f`.

Comment: Can you rewrite `f` so that it takes array input? When you want performance in code like this, you want to avoid Python loops in favor of matrix operations. If you can’t change `f` then you have to loop over 30k calls to `f`. If you can change `f` you may be able to avoid any Python loops.

Comment: np.vectorize passes scalar elements (after broadcasting) not 1d arrays.

Comment: As long as `f` is a complex black box, the iteration mechanism doesn't make much difference in speed.  It still has to call `f` once for each combination of arrays, which takes most of the time.  You could experiment with creating the arrays so you can use `zip(A,B,C)`, but transpose is cheap so that probably doesn't change much.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks, this makes sense. `f` is indeed a rather complex one, so maybe I should try and reframe the whole problem (not in scope of this particular question).